# Gnuplot - Multi-branch fit with errors

Tags: gnuplot

I want to do a multi-branch fit with gnuplot. I have a set of data containing values for xyerror the following data.

```
x y1 dx dy1

x y2 dx dy2
```

I was able to do a fit without x and y errors.

```
fit f(x,y) 'files.dat' using 1:-1:2 via a,b,c
```

I want to know how to do a multi-branch fit with x and y errors?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell your case is already mentioned in the gnuplot manual about fit:

> As an example, if one has 2 independent variables, and errors for the first independent variable and the
>   dependent variable, one uses the errors x,z qualifier, and a using qualifier with 5 columns, which are
>   interpreted as x:y:z:sx:sz (where x and y are the independent variables, z the dependent variable, and sx and
>   sz the standard deviations of x and z).

x ("x" in your data file) and y (line number) are your two independent variables, z ("y" in your data file) is the dependent variable. For your case the fit command should look like

`fit f(x,y) 'files.dat' using 1:-1:2:3:4 errors x,z via a,b,c`